# Convert markdown table to json with python

Tags: python, parsing, markdown

I am trying to figure out, what is the easiest way to convert some markdown table text into json using only python. For example, consider this as input string:

```markdown
| Some Title | Some Description             | Some Number |
|------------|------------------------------|-------------|
| Dark Souls | This is a fun game           | 5           |
| Bloodborne | This one is even better      | 2           |
| Sekiro     | This one is also pretty good | 110101      |
```

The output should be like this:

```json
[
    {"Some Title":"Dark Souls","Some Description":"This is a fun game","Some Number":5},
    {"Some Title":"Bloodborne","Some Description":"This one is even better","Some Number":2},
    {"Some Title":"Sekiro","Some Description":"This one is also pretty good","Some Number":110101}
]
```

Note: Ideally, the output should be RFC 8259 compliant, aka use double quotes " instead of single quotes ' around they key value pairs.

I've seen some JS libraries that do that, but nothing for python only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat it as a multi-line string and parse it line by line while splitting at `\n` and `|`

Simple code that does that:

```
import json

my_str='''| Some Title | Some Description             | Some Number |
|------------|------------------------------|-------------|
| Dark Souls | This is a fun game           | 5           |
| Bloodborne | This one is even better      | 2           |
| Sekiro     | This one is also pretty good | 110101      |'''

def mrkd2json(inp):
    lines = inp.split('\n')
    ret=[]
    keys=[]
    for i,l in enumerate(lines):
        if i==0:
            keys=[_i.strip() for _i in l.split('|')]
        elif i==1: continue
        else:
            ret.append({keys[_i]:v.strip() for _i,v in enumerate(l.split('|')) if  _i>0 and _i<len(keys)-1})
    return json.dumps(ret, indent = 4) 
print(mrkd2json(my_str))
```

```
[
    {
        "Some Title": "Dark Souls",
        "Some Description": "This is a fun game",
        "Some Number": "5"
    },
    {
        "Some Title": "Bloodborne",
        "Some Description": "This one is even better",
        "Some Number": "2"
    },
    {
        "Some Title": "Sekiro",
        "Some Description": "This one is also pretty good",
        "Some Number": "110101"
    }
]
```

PS: Don't know about any library that does that, will update if I find anything!

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the input! I didn't even think of simply going with string splitting - definitely a good approach. One thing that just came to mind (even tho not stated in my original post) is that we lose information about alignment per cells. Do you have an idea for that? Maybe by having an additional field for every cell that stores the alignment or so?

Comment: @Kyu96 Like whether it was centred or left/right-aligned? That's interesting, let me read about it a little bit! But if your original question is resolved, please mark this as an answer!

Comment: Yea, thats what i mean (left, center and right alignment). Let me know if you have an idea for that. Also, I noticed one minor problem with your solution - It uses single quotes instead of double quotes, which is not valid according to RFC 8259. And doing a simple `.replace("'", '"')` is not an option, because a quote could be part of the content in a cell. I'll mark it as resolved if you can find a solution for that :)

Comment: @Kyu96 just use `json.dumps`, solution updated

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it! Let me know if you have an idea for the alignment

Answer (score 2):

My approach was very similar to @Kuldeep Singh Sidhu's:

```py
md_table = """
| Some Title | Some Description             | Some Number |
|------------|------------------------------|-------------|
| Dark Souls | This is a fun game           | 5           |
| Bloodborne | This one is even better      | 2           |
| Sekiro     | This one is also pretty good | 110101      |
"""

result = []

for n, line in enumerate(md_table[1:-1].split('\n')):
    data = {}
    if n == 0:
        header = [t.strip() for t in line.split('|')[1:-1]]
    if n > 1:
        values = [t.strip() for t in line.split('|')[1:-1]]
        for col, value in zip(header, values):
            data[col] = value
        result.append(data)
```

Result is:

```
[{'Some Title': 'Dark Souls',
  'Some Description': 'This is a fun game',
  'Some Number': '5'},
 {'Some Title': 'Bloodborne',
  'Some Description': 'This one is even better',
  'Some Number': '2'},
 {'Some Title': 'Sekiro',
  'Some Description': 'This one is also pretty good',
  'Some Number': '110101'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how one could ensure that the alignment in the table is not lost?